# arguments/parameters to the drupal 7 block module

Tags: drupal, module

i want to make a block module with a few parameters. so once the parameters are changed then different results ll come up. i have done very easily with views but i need more on the results and fields which i cant do in views. but how can i achieve that in modules? i made the form but somehow i cant show the results. i want to show the form separate and results separate...

```
<?php

function googlemap_block_info()
{
    $blocks = array();
    $blocks['googlemap'] = array(
        'info' => t('googlemap Block'),
        'page callback' => drupal_get_form('googlemap_get_form'),
    );
    return $blocks;
}

function googlemap_get_regions(){
    return get_field_allowed_values( 'field_region_area' );
}
function googlemap_get_services(){
    return get_field_allowed_values( 'field_senior_care_service' );
}
function googlemap_data($form, &$form_state){
       print '<div><h1>'.$form_state['values']['region'].'</h1></div>';

} 
function googlemap_submit_handler($form, &$form_state){
    googlemap_data($form, &$form_state);
    drupal_set_message( $form_state['values']['region'], $status );

}
function googlemap_get_form($form, &$form_state)
{
    $form['#id'] = 'googlemap_form';
    $form['#method'] = 'post';


    $form['service'] = array(
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#title' => t('Select a Service'),
        '#options' => googlemap_get_services(),
        '#required' => TRUE,
    );
    $form['region'] = array(
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#title' => t('Select your region'),
        '#options' => googlemap_get_regions(),
        '#required' => TRUE,
    );
    $form['actions']['submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('Show Care Homes'),
        '#weight' => 100,
        '#submit' => array('googlemap_submit_handler'),
        '#attributes' => array('id' => 'find-button', 'style' => 'cursor: pointer; text-indent: -9999px;')
    );

    return $form;
}
function googlemap_block_view($delta = '')
{

    switch($delta){
        case 'googlemap':
         $block['subject'] = t('Google Maps');
         $block['content'] = drupal_get_form('googlemap_get_form');
    break;
    }
    return $block;
}

?>
```